# GeoLocation using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, geolocation

I copied paste following code and I am a noob at this. So can you point out error please? I am sorry for asking such a stupid question.

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
    <h3>Client side IP geolocation using <a href="http://ipinfo.io">ipinfo.io</a></h3>
    <hr/>
    <div id="ip"></div>
    <div id="address"></div>
    <hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>
</BODY>

</HTML>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
</script>
```

Comment: Are you asking to convert that code in PHP equivalent?

Comment: IDK Just want to run this and get geolocation based on IP address and get address of visitor. Will it work?

Comment: I saved this file as location.html

Comment: Did you test it? if you view location.html on your browser what do you see?

Comment: Just the html text. I'll copy paste here:

Client side IP geolocation using ipinfo.io

Full response:

Comment: I have run this code on my site they are not provide "region" and city is blank.

Comment: Why is it not working for me? Additional info: I am running it on local server using wamp and my system is connected to pretty fast internet if it matters!

Comment: My suggestion is use HTML5 latitude and longitude concept after that you get proper address of user.
Your using ip to location that is provide user internet provider address not user exact address

Comment: Can you tell me how to do so please? Like proper code? @Prasanna

Comment: Do you want ip addrees and user address or only user address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HtML5 using get user latitude, longitude and get current user address.

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Address: <div id="address"></div></p>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var currgeocoder;

        //Set geo location lat and long
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position, html5Error) {
            geo_loc = processGeolocationResult(position);
            currLatLong = geo_loc.split(",");
            initializeCurrent(currLatLong[0], currLatLong[1]);
        });

        //Get geo location result
        function processGeolocationResult(position) {
            html5Lat = position.coords.latitude; //Get latitude
            html5Lon = position.coords.longitude; //Get longitude
            html5TimeStamp = position.timestamp; //Get timestamp
            html5Accuracy = position.coords.accuracy; //Get accuracy in meters
            return (html5Lat).toFixed(8) + ", " + (html5Lon).toFixed(8);
        }

        //Check value is present or
        function initializeCurrent(latcurr, longcurr) {
            currgeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            console.log(latcurr + "-- ######## --" + longcurr);

            if (latcurr != '' && longcurr != '') {
                //call google api function
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latcurr, longcurr);
                return getCurrentAddress(myLatlng);
            }
        }

        //Get current address
        function getCurrentAddress(location) {
            currgeocoder.geocode({
                'location': location
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    console.log(results[0]);
                    $("#address").html(results[0].formatted_address);
                } else {
                    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hmy7e0fs/

Answer (score 0):

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>

</HEAD>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://js.maxmind.com/js/geoip.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
alert('hello');
    $("#ip").html("IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
</script>
<BODY>
<h3>Client side IP geolocation using <a href="http://ipinfo.io">ipinfo.io</a></h3>

 <hr/>
<div id="ip"></div>
<div id="address"></div>
<hr/>Full response: <pre id="details"></pre>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<?php 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$locationArray = unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $ip));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($locationArray);

?>
```

I would like to prefer geoplugin better than http://ipinfo.io as its request limit per minute is max.

For more info please visit: http://www.geoplugin.com/

Comment: Yeah. BTW you should check HTML5 one. IDK which one of two I will use. But yours definitely useful man!

Comment: You need to keep two things in mind here . (1) using REMOTE_ADDR should be the last of several other things to check first.  For example in my case it used the server and returned 404 for this call. (2) this is only going to be roughly accurate. HTML5 would be much better (but hard to implement) or a pay service etc. .